ASP.NET Core docker project build - copying the "Program.cs" code file issue
I've used Visual Studio 2022 to generate an ASP.NET Core project with Docker support (checked the checkboxes at project creation). I tried  modifying the dockerfile of the generated project - like removing the Directory.Build.props and Directory.Packages.props copy commands.
The end result looks like this (the 11-th line is commented on purpose):
# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
# COPY ["Program.cs", "TempWorkerService/"]
COPY ["TempWorkerService.csproj", "TempWorkerService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./TempWorkerService/TempWorkerService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TempWorkerService"
RUN dotnet build "./TempWorkerService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./TempWorkerService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TempWorkerService.dll"]

The content of the project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>f9a674f5-174b-4872-be35-53b84e790611</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Other files within the project are default. The issue is - running the docker build -t TempWorkerService . fails at the dotnet build step.
The console output is:
[+] Building 3.1s (13/17)                                              
docker:desktop-linux  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            
0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 1.35kB                                                                             
0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0                                                  
0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0                                   
0.1s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  
0.0s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    
0.0s  => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0@sha256:9461e0688e9141bd312da7afef640bb551529ad70511209509
0.0s  => [internal] load build context                                                                                  
0.0s  => => transferring context: 4.73kB                                                                                
0.0s  => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0                                                              
0.0s  => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                
0.0s  => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [TempWorkerService.csproj, TempWorkerService/]                                         
0.0s  => CACHED [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./TempWorkerService/TempWorkerService.csproj"                        
0.0s  => CACHED [build 5/7] COPY . .                                                                                    
0.0s  => CACHED [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/TempWorkerService                                                              
0.0s  => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "./TempWorkerService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                 
2.8s  [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "./TempWorkerService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
0.801   Determining projects to restore...
1.109   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
2.770 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TempWorkerService/TempWorkerService.csproj]
2.777
2.778 Build FAILED.

But - modifying the dockerfile by uncommenting the COPY ["Program.cs", "TempWorkerService/"] line seems to be fixing the problem, running the docker build -t TempWorkerService . after that gives the successful output.
From what I understood about the COPY command: the COPY . . is supposed to copy everything from the build context - the project directory - to current workdir, the "/src". The fact that the Program.cs is not copied, apparently, refutes that.
How does it work then?

My guess is that it needs it for the dotnet restore step and somehow not having it there leads to the error you see.

Not sure I understand. The RUN dotnet restore "./TempWorkerService/TempWorkerService.csproj" is the 7-th line in the dockerfile, right before the COPY . . command. Or is there a different dotnet restore you're writing about?

The line right before COPY . .. Maybe it saves some data that it extracts from Program.cs that is used by the build command later. But I don't know. It's just a guess.

My bad, the dockerfile content was incomplete. Fixed that.
